# Store Docker volume on external hard drive

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, btrfs

I am trying to store the data of my container on an 'external hard drive' (`/dev/xvdd`) that is mounted at `/mnt/datadbs`.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: "3":

services:
  ...

volumes:
  prometheus-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: btrfs
      device: /mnt/dataebs
```

When I start the container, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: for prometheus  Cannot create container for service prometheus: failed to mount local volume: mount /mnt/dataebs:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ubuntu_prometheus-data/_data: block device required
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Eventually, I want to be able to store several docker volumes on the 'external hard drive'.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your named volume declaration type to "bind" instead of "btrfs".

So it would be something like this:

```
volumes:
  prometheus-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /mnt/dataebs
      o: bind
```

You can also bind mount directly in your service declaration, so something like this:

```
app:
    image: appimage
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /mnt/dataebs:/container/path
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still getting the same error "block device required" if I change the type to "bind". As far as the second option is concerned, I don't want to use this options because this creates issues with the ownership of the directory (/mnt/dataebs) since the mounted directory is mounted by root. Is there any other option?

Comment: I would try option 2 just to see if you get the same error.

Comment: I updated option 1 after doing some testing, try it and let me know if you still have issues.